# Begininvoke executed with a significant delay

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a console application that receives messages from clients and sends it to the server via websockets.

```
    // there we receive the request from the client app
    private void onMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
       Task.Factory.StartNew((Action) (() =>
      {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;

        sendAsync(opcode, new MemoryStream(data), callback, msg);
      }), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness, TaskScheduler.Default).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private void sendAsync(Opcode opcode, Stream stream, Action<bool> completed, string data)
    {
        _logger.Info("before invoke " + DateTime.Now);

        Func<Opcode, Stream, string, bool> sender = send;
        sender.BeginInvoke(
            opcode,
            stream, data,
            ar =>
            {
                completed(sent);
            },
            null);
    }

    private bool send(Opcode opcode, Stream stream, string msg)
    {
        _logger.Info("before lock " + DateTime.Now);
        lock (_forSend)
        {
            // write to the stream
        }
    }
```

How you can see we use BeginInvoke in sendAsync. In most cases, everything works fine, but sometimes there is a significant delay before a delegate was executed and we receive such logs:

```
 Win32 Thread Id 29796: before invoke 11/20/2019 21:40:52
 Win32 Thread Id 36976: before lock 11/20/2019 21:41:22
```

Why can this happen?

Comment: First of all, why do you need to mix the `Task` and async delegates using `BeginInvoke`? Second, as you can see in log, the thread id is different, `send` is executed on different thread from thread pool. If you have a lot of threads (for every client, I suppose). it will take a time to create a new thread

Comment: You need to avoid using a delegate's BeginInvoke() method.  It doesn't port to .NETCore, you have very little control over how it executes and gums-up the threadpool.  The latter problem explains delays.  Use the WebSocket's SendAsync() method instead.

Comment: There is much more code in onMessage and we need to execute it asynchronously, because of this we use Task.Factory.StartNew. I understand that there can be delay before a new thread will be created, but in this case it took 30 seconds.It’s not clear why so long

Comment: Pavel, it is legacy code. BeginInvoke used in sendAsync because in some cases it called from a synchronous context. In this context, it looks really strange, but I don’t think it could be the cause for such a delay

Comment: "legacy code" in this scenario just means "the previous programmer got it wrong".  Happens all the time, you're not stuck at doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not an answer you are expecting, but I got into some similar problems before. In almost all the cases, it is not the threadpool is too busy, instead it were always developer error.

Judging by the log, as the time between the log is **30** seconds, I would say some developer possibly put a 30 second timer or a lock with timeout for 30 seconds. As 30 seconds is a magic number for developers (lots of command has a default timeout for 30 seconds as well).

So I will bet it is a user error.

Comment: How you can see the only thing we do between these two messages is what we use BeginInvoke. If there is any long running thread in the thread pool why the new thread wasn’t created when we use BeginInvoke? I thought if there is some slow work item in the thread  pool it can add threads as frequently as twice a second